# Dynamically return a javascript file in Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Is it possible to have an asp page return a javascript file dynamically in classic ASP?  What I'm trying to do is return a specific javascript file to a calling asp page by passing through another asp page.  The 'pass through' page will inspect a server variable and based on a setting with either return scriptA.js or scriptB.js to the calling asp page.  The calling asp page needs to use the returned .js for navigation menus.

It's been over 7 years since I've done any Classic ASP, and got sucked into helping out on a project.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to create the js file dynamically or just the inclusion of the scriptA vs. scriptB?  More specifically, are scriptA and scriptB static on the file system?

Comment: The scripts already exist.  I need to "choose" one of them based on a variable.  I'd like to have IIS redirect any requests for the script directory to an asp page that will return the appropriate .js....if that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use [Server.CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524786%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)("[Scripting.FilesystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea5ht6ax%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)") 
to read the appropriate javascript file and use [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to output the appropriate javascript file.   Remember to set the content type to JavaScript.

[Response.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) = "application/x-javascript"

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't seem to work.  I think the problem is that I'm trying to redirect all requests to a folder with all of the .js files to a single .asp file that will do the Response.Write of the appropriate .js file.  I'm trying this in IIS 5.1 with redirects on a folder.  I am able to get the javascript to write out to a page, however, when I try to get the src from an asp page, all I get in firebug is:  " Failed to load source for: myscript.js".  I'm beginning to think that this is not possible to do.

Comment: @brutus35.  It might be a case of firebug not being able to deal with the redirect when you try to open the .js file.  I just a ran a quick test on IIS6 and IE. It worked like you are wanting it to.  Maybe you could put a javascript alert to see if it is working?

Comment: I'm not getting any of the javascript back from the original calling page with <script src="/script/test/menu.js">.  In IIS I have anything requesting a file from /script/test to get redirected to an asp page in a nother folder.  That asp page is what I have doing the Response.Write of the javascript code, which I want the original page to be able to use....

Comment: Ha looks like you're correct.  Seems to be working now, thanks for suggesting the alert.  One more question, if I wanted to get the url of the request that forced the redirect, in this case `<script src="/script/test/menu.js"> `, how could I do that?  I want to be able to tell what .js file was originally requested.

Comment: Ii was able to get this to work by setting the redirect variable to ?script=$V, then just grabbing the script name off of the querystring.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically include files like this:

```
if Request.QueryString("param")="2" then  
    Server.Execute("page1.asp") 
else 
    Server.Execute("page2.asp") 
end if
```

Where page1.asp and page2.asp have js files embedded in them (only).

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=<%
if($Request->ServerVariables(URL)->item() eq 'here') { %>"something.js"<% }
else {  %>"somethingelse.js"<% }
%>></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JScript in Classic ASP

```
var curFileName = "";
if(Server("Variable") == 'true'){ curFileName = page1.js; }
else{ curFileName = page2.js; }

Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript src='" + curFileName + "'><\/script>");
```